# Is Bluefish being updated?

Tags: bluefish

Is Bluefish being maintained ? I mean is it getting any updates at all ? By the way this editor is great. Very happy with it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes...

The last version of bluefish is `2.2.10` which has been released at January 27, 2017 4 months ago [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluefish_(text_editor)), [[2]](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html).

And the versions in Ubuntu repositories are:

```
 bluefish | 2.2.2-1 | precise/universe 
 bluefish | 2.2.5-1 | trusty/universe  
 bluefish | 2.2.6-2 | vivid/universe   
 bluefish | 2.2.7-2 | xenial/universe  
 bluefish | 2.2.7-2 | yakkety/universe 
 bluefish | 2.2.9-1 | zesty/universe   
 bluefish | 2.2.9-1 | artful/universe
```

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like it does](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bluefish/).

If you want something with more modern look, just go for Sublime, Atom, Visual Studio Code or Brackets (for webdesign)

Comment: I don't care about the look much. But wanna be using software that is being updated. Nice !